# Setup MS SQL Remote Connection & Connect From Linux Hosting With PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

Oke soo as the title said, 
I have SQL Server 2005 installed on my windows 7 at home, and I have a website which is using linux (Ubuntu 14.04, can be upgraded if necessary),and the questions is

1. How to setup remote connection for SQL Server
2. What kind of driver or addons that I need to use for PHP on linux? SQLSRV ? is the driver safe to use?
3. Example for the driver that used to connect to SQL Server
4. And I see that people use ip to connect remotely, how do I get the ip for connecting to my own pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To setup remote connections follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option
2. Yes the driver is safe. Getting started instructions here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/windows/
3. Example code

   ```
   <?php
        $serverName = "localhost";
   $connectionOptions = array(
       "Database" => "SampleDB",
       "Uid" => "sa",
       "PWD" => "your_password"
   );
   //Establishes the connection
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
   if($conn)
       echo "Connected!"
   ?>
   ```
4. You can get ip from ipconfig